# Beginner Help. For setting up dual OS

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I have downloaded the latest ubuntu onto a external hard drive, but i cant seem to figure out how to open it and run that os from the HD. I'm in school so i need to keep my primary OS as windows for conveniency purposes. Is there a way i can have a duel os, pulling one from a External Hard Drive?

John

Comment: Do you just want live installer on a flash drive or a full install on external drive? UEFI or BIOS install.

Comment: Im hoping to do a dual boot so i can swap back and forth between both os depending on what im trying to do. and for the bios install would i need to go through the bios menu when im booting?

Answer (score -2):

you should install it on a sdcard or a usb flash drive so you can dualboot.
if you want to stop using ubuntu do a hard reset and reinstall windows.
I hope it help!

Comment: What's "a hard reset", and why reinstall Windows?

Comment: It is fully reseting a computer. Removing ubuntu removing every data and even windows. You want to reinstall windows because you want it to work again.

Comment: Well, none of it is necessary, especially if Ubuntu is installed on an external device, such as sdcard or usb flash drive. Should the user choose to stop using Ubuntu, it's enough to unplug the device.

Comment: No. grub would just go to rescue mode and your stuck.